# Converting lat/long to EPSG:27700 in geometry generator expression

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, expression, geometry-generator

I have incorporated a geometry generator into a style in QGIS 3.4 which creates a callout line from a feature to its relevant spatial position.

For reasons out of my control our projects use CRS: EPSG:27700 but some of the layers we need to import use CRS: EPSG:4326. QGIS handles this fine and can plot the features, but the geometry generator cannot.

I know I could convert beforehand but this is not practical for all our users so I just want the expression to handle this for them.

I am looking for a method to convert from `'4326'` to `'27700'` within the expression but I am not currently aware if this is possible.

**My current geometry generator expression**

```
make_line(make_point($x, $y), make_point("Longitude", "Latitude"))
```

The `"Longitude"` and `"Latitude"` fields relate to the fields in the relevant layer which is projected with EPSG:4326.

Comment: Have you tried something with `transform($geomerty, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:27700')`?

Comment: Have you had a look at the `transform`-expression? I am not exactly sure, where to place it, though. Based on Taras comment, I'd say `make_line(make_point($x,$y),transform(make_point("Longitude",Latitude"),'EPSG:4326','EPSG:27700'))`.

Comment: Thank you both - I did not consider this. I have just tried @Erik suggestion but this is still pointing towards the original lat/long position

Comment: Had a play around but cannot get this method to work - I have tried transforming each field independently with no avail.

Comment: Try adding new fields to the attribute table with `transform("Longitude",'EPSG:4326','EPSG:27700')` and then using these fields instead of Longitude/Latitude.

Comment: @Erik thanks for the suggestion - I am aware that this is possible but I do not want all users doing this every time they import the data into QGIS. I just wanted the expression to do this so the style can be applied instantly.

Comment: The geometry generator uses the layer's CRS. If the layer is in EPSG:4326 and the lat/long coordinates are also in EPSG:4326, the geometry generator should render `make_point("Longitude",Latitude")` correctly.

Comment: @csk so does this mean I have to have my project CRS set to ESPG: 4326? If this is the case then I guess what I am asking is not possible.

Comment: See here how to do it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386126/88814