# Apply transformation to layer on the fly when using tools like Buffer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, expression, geometry-generator

I know that you can have an on-the-fly transformation on a layer when rendering on the canvas, but is there a way to run a tool like Buffer where the layer should be re-projected on-the-fly just before buffering? For example, I have points in WGS84 but I want to buffer them in the linear unit of a specific national grid, or perhaps of the project default CRS.

I have looked around online for this but it is difficult to find any sources which are not referring to the normal "on-the-fly" transformations used when rendering the layer on the canvas.

Comment: [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html?highlight=buffer#variations-in-buffering) states that "The numerical values have to be defined in map units according to the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) used with the data."

Comment: Right-click layer / Export /Save features as... and set the CRS you want to use for buffering. By the way: what QGIS-version do you use?

Comment: @Babel, that's what I'm already doing which is why I was hoping that there was a more streamlined way. Version is 3.10.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that applying geometry generator and first transform from WGS84 to a projected CRS, applying the buffer in meters and than transform back to WGS84. See my case:

- Project CRS: 3857 (WebMercator)
- Layer CRS: 4326 (WGS84)
- CRS used for buffering: 2056 (projected CRS used for Switzerland)

Use this expression in geometry generator to get a buffer of 100 meters (buffer measured in 2056, converted to 4326, transformed "on-the-fly" to 3857):

```
transform (
    buffer (
        transform (
            $geometry, 
            'epsg:4326',
            'epsg:2056'
        ), 
        100
    ),
    'epsg:2056',
    'epsg:4326'
)
```

*Screenshot: Point layer in EPSG:4326, Project CRS in EPSG:3857, buffer applyied in EPSG:2056:*
[image]

*The same buffers visualized with Project CRS in EPSG 4326:*
[image]

*And the same setting with Project in EPSG 2056:*
[image]